# Having multiple boolean condtions in a "if" statement?

Tags: if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to write an "if" statement with multiple boolean conditions. Right now, I have 5 different boolean variables. In the "if" statement, I want to print different things according to which boolean variable is true. The code I have right now prints out the results from each of the "if" statements, instead of only from the one that is true.

```
boolean result = Arrays.equals(user, Jamie); //compares the arrays
boolean result2 = Arrays.equals(user, David);
boolean result3 = Arrays.equals(user, Sally);
boolean result4 = Arrays.equals(user, Susan);
boolean result5 = Arrays.equals(user, Mary);

if (result = true) {
        Address a = new Address (20, 201107, "Pizza", "blue"); //makes the different objects
        printLines (a); //calls the printLines method to print out the "Secret information" about the user
} 
if (result2 = true) {
        Address b = new Address (56, 211045, "Noodles", "Pink");
        printLines (b);
}
if (result3 = true) {
        Address c = new Address (46, 329432, "Hamburgers", "Green");
        printLines (c); 
}
if (result4 = true) {
        Address d = new Address (80, 322810, "Fried Rice", "Yellow");
        printLines (d);
}
if (result5 = true) {
        Address e = new Address (35, 405029, "Steak", "Red");
        printLines (e);
}
else {
        System.out.println ("Password is wrong");
}
```

Basically, what I want the program to do is only print object "a" when "result" is true. However, right now, when "result" is true, the program prints all the objects (a, b, c, d, and e) instead of just printing "a". How can I fix it?

Comment: result = true. it seems like an assignment , use == for checking conditions/

Answer (score 0):

Use `else if` to ensure that only a single closure will ever be evaluated:

```
if (result) {
    Address a = new Address (20, 201107, "Pizza", "blue"); //makes the different objects
    printLines (a); //calls the printLines method to print out the "Secret information" about the user
} 
else if (result2) {
    Address b = new Address (56, 211045, "Noodles", "Pink");
    printLines (b);
}
else if (result3) {
    Address c = new Address (46, 329432, "Hamburgers", "Green");
    printLines (c); 
}
else if (result4) {
    Address d = new Address (80, 322810, "Fried Rice", "Yellow");
    printLines (d);
}
else if (result5) {
    Address e = new Address (35, 405029, "Steak", "Red");
    printLines (e);
}
else {
    System.out.println ("Password is wrong");
}
```

As your code currently stands, if multiple result boolean variables were `true` then mulitple `if` blocks might be evaluated.

Comment: When I do that, it only ever prints the first "if" statement, why is that?

Comment: @celinatala Yes, isn't that the behavior you want?

Comment: The first statement is always true because `=` is for assignment. You want `==` for comparison. Or just `if(result)` because `result == true` is redundant.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. What I want to do is to print the object according to which result variable is true. For example, if "result" is false, but "result2" is true, then I want to print object "b".

Comment: @celinatala You should be using `if ... else if ... else if ... else` ... this is the major problem with your code.  By using only `if` statements, you leave open the possibility for multiple blocks of code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (result)
```

instead of

```
if (result == true)
```

The below code illustrates...

```
package com.johanw;

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        boolean value = false;
        // the below condition is true, i.e. value == false
        if (value == false) {
            System.out.println("Value equals false");
        }
        // the below condition is also true and this is what is the recommended approach for evaluating conditions
        if (!value) {
            System.out.println("Value equals false, i.e. !value is a true condition");
        }
        // the below is another illustration of evaluating a condition, comparing the condition (1 == 1) with true
        if ((1 == 1) == true) {
            System.out.println("The condition 1 == 1 equals true");
        }
        // the below condition is also true and also the recommended approach for evaluating a condition
        if (1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("The condition 1 == 1 equals true");
        }
        // the below line is assigning a value true to the variable value and then evaluting the condition, which is true
        if (value = true) {
            System.out.println("Value was assigned the value true and therefore results in a true condition");
        }
        // the below line is assigning a value false to the variable value and then evaluting the condition, which is false, and hence the else condition is valid
        if (value = false) {
        } else {
            System.out.println("Value was assigned the value false and therefore results in a false condition");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add to this answer.  It is currently just a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TimBiegeleisen. I've updated the answer